# Avoiding extra event call in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load data in `Bootstrap Modal` using `ajax` request. This is my sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/f97gpwte/2/

HTML :

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="button">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div id="exec_count"></div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS :

```
var count=0

$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        count++;
        jQuery("#exec_count").append("<span>"+count+"</span></br>");
    });

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        count=0;
        jQuery("#exec_count").append("</br>");
    });
});
```

The problem is, after each time button is pressed the event call is increased by one. So every time number of ajax calls are also increased with the event call. In the example, I have replace the ajax code with display event call count.

I am not able to find any solution for avoiding extra calls.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to hook up the events outside the click event. Basically you are adding an event handler every time you click.

Comment: Binding event handler inside another event handler is very bad idea itself in most cases. And it causes all kind of troubles in situations like this.

Comment: Ok now I got it, thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers is being added every time the button is being clicked. You will need to move your event handlers outside of the click event.

```
var count=0

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    count++;
    jQuery("#exec_count").append("<span>"+count+"</span></br>");
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    count=0;
    jQuery("#exec_count").append("</br>");
});

$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```